# NuxtJs Build SPA on Nginx server

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application, nuxt.js

i want to deploy my Single Page Application on my Nginx server

so i run

```
npm run build
```

and i uploaded the dist folder to my server, and it works fine with the static pages, but if on the dynamic pages that have a dynamic url i got the below error

> ERROR 404 - PAGE NOT FOUND

can you please help me with this.

Comment: Well nuxt docs told you that it won't work as expected with dynamic routes. Your best bet is to stop using routes like `/page/sub-page/:id` and resort to `/page/sub-page?id`.

Answer (score 5):

Your webserver is not aware of the routing inside your Vue application, so you'll need to have Nginx point all requests to the application to the index.html and after that Vue routing will take over. The documentation can be found [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html).

The required configuration snippet copied from there is the following:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but where is should add this configuration snippet?